# multi-threading of a matrix multiplication in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to create n threads and that each thread computes an entire row of the result matrix. I have tried the following code,

```
import numpy
import random
import threading

class MatrixMult(threading.Thread):
    """A thread which computes the i,j entry of A * B"""
    def __init__(self, A, B, i):
        super(MatrixMult, self).__init__()
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.i = i
        #self.j = j                                                             
    def run(self):
        print "Computing %i, %i" % (self.i, self.i)
        x = 0
        result=[]
        for k in range(self.A.shape[0])
            x += self.A[self.i,k] * self.B[k,self.i  
        self.result=x
        print "Completed %i, %i" % (self.i, self.j)

def mult(n):
    """A function to randomly create two n x n matrices and multiply them"""
    # Create two random matrices                                                
    A = numpy.zeros((n,n))
    B = numpy.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            A[i,j] = random.randrange(0, 100)
            B[i,j] = random.randrange(0, 100)
    # Create and start the threads                                              
    threads = []
    for i in range(n):
       # for j in range(n):                                                     
        t = MatrixMult(A, B, i)
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
    for t in threads: t.join()
    C = numpy.zeros((n,n))
    for t in threads:
        C[t.i] = t.result
    return C
print multi(30)
```

however it prints out many weird matrices:

```
[ 66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.
   66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.
   66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.  66695.
   66695.  66695.  66695.]
 [ 88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.
   88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.
   88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.  88468.
   88468.  88468.  88468.]]
```

anyone see a problem in my code? I don't see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the supposed output?

Comment: What indentation do you intend to have in the lines immediately following `def self(...)`, `x=0` and `t = MatrixMult(...)`?

Comment: thats the indentation like it is now. output is hard to say, because it makes random numbers and should multiple, for sure it will not look like this

Answer (score 3):

Your code sets

```
C[t.i] = t.result
```

which sets an entire row of `C` to the value `t.result`, which is a scalar. I see some commented stuff about `j` in there; you presumably want to account for that, and also fix

```
x += self.A[self.i,k] * self.B[k,self.i
```

to use `j` (and also not be a syntax error). As-is, it seems like you're computing `C[i, i]` and then assigning that value to the whole row.

Also: you know this code is guaranteed to be much, much, much slower than `np.dot`, right? Between doing tight loops in python, distributing computational work across threads despite the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), and also being [an inefficient algorithm for matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) in the first place. If your goal is actually to speed up matrix multiplies using multiple cores, link your numpy to MKL, OpenBLAS, or ACML, use `np.dot`, and call it a day.

Comment: but i want each thread to compute each row. also when i assign C[t.i,t.j]=t.result then i got an error that MatrixMult' object has no attribute 'result'

Comment: Well, then you're going to need to compute a whole row...currently you're only computing a single element. Not sure on the missing `result` error.

Comment: how would you pass the whole row though? Is it the way I have the threads made

Comment: Can someone upload the fixed code for  this problem?@djs

Comment: @HarshNagarkar As I noted in the answer, you really don't want to do things this way; it's going to be *much* slower than using a proper multithreaded BLAS implementation.